# Find sentences begining and ending with hash

Tags: java, regex, string

I am working on detecting sentences which start and end with hashtags. As of now, I only have code to find words, which is part of this mechanism. How can I find sentences depending upon case below.

Case 1:

```
Hello, #how are you# today.
```

In this case, I want to detect `how are you`. Now if there is only a word, then the above case is to be ignored.

Case 2:

```
Hello, #how are you #today.
```

In this case, only words `#how` and `#today` are found, which I already have working. No sentences here as words don't end with hashtag.

Code:

```
@Override
public List<String> findHashTags(String text){
    if(text == null){
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    String[] tagSet = text.split(" ");
    Set<String> sortedTags = new HashSet<>();
    List<String> processedTags = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String tags : tagSet){
         if(tags.startsWith("#")){
             sortedTags.add(tags);
         }
    }
    processedTags.addAll(sortedTags);
    return processedTags;
}
```

## Updated code

```
@Override
    public List<String> findHashTags(String text){
        if(text == null){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        Set<String> sortedTags = new HashSet<>();
        List<String> processedTags = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#\\b.*?\\b#|\\B#\\w+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()){
            String outString = matcher.group();
            outString = outString.replace("#","");
            outString = outString.replace(",","");
            sortedTags.add(outString);
        }
        processedTags.addAll(sortedTags);

        return processedTags;
    }
```

Comment: You should search for end words after start word is found, otherwise this whole thing is ineffective.

Comment: As fir the code, why not contract it to http://rextester.com/ZNXBJ65797? You may remove commas from group 2 if you wish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a regex to match substrings from a `#` that is followed with a word char and up to the first `#` that is preceded with a word char, or match a `#` that is not preceded with a word char and then has any 1+ word chars.

```
#\b.*?\b#|\B#\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pWtYqa/1/)

You may precise it a bit if you want to exclude substrings like `#_ s#`  by turning the first `\b` into `(?=\p{L})` / `(?=[a-zA-Z])` to require a letter.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Ts7e4b):

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
String s = "Hello, #how are you# today. Hello, #how are you #today.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#\\b.*?\\b#|\\B#\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    results.add(matcher.group());
} 
System.out.println(results); 
// => [#how are you#, #how, #today]
```

Comment: Trying this now

Comment: I think that you can add a groups: `#(\b.*?\b)#|\B#(\w+)`

Comment: @oleg.cherednik That depends on what needs to be extracted. See [this Java demo with your suggestion](https://ideone.com/jkdgxS).

Comment: This worked like a charm man, great regex... Thank you. I will accept your answer in 3 minutes because of SO rules... Thank you. :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew very nice and simple regex, I was not aware you can negate a `\b`. beautiful!

Comment: Hi Wiktor. I had added the code on our server, but for some reason, it seems to be causing server hangups, where it's just waiting. After 2 days, we were able to isolate the issue to regex. Is there any chance, that this could be because of backtracking. I have added the code I am using at bottom of main post. Can you please check it out. Thanks. :D

Comment: @WeareBorg You can't make it any better without defining the expected match requirements further. You may try `"#\\b([^#]*)\\b#|\\B#(\\w+)"` but it may "overlook" some valid patterns while working much faster and safer.

Comment: I only have 2 requirements : 1) find words which start with hashtag 2) Find sentences which are enclosed in hashtags. I have to look for something better as this seems to slow down the server to nothing.

Comment: @WeareBorg What is a word? I think `\w+` will match "words" and the second part of the regex works well. What is a sentence? What chars can it include? If any, you can't but rely on `#\b(.*?)\b#`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. A word to be found by regex is just the one which starts with # and ends with a space. For sentence to be found by regex, no rules other than it should be enclosed in 2 #. Example #Hello, how are you#. Example of word, #hello, how are you. I am trying the regex you gave in ur last comment now.

Comment: The last regex didn't work as well. The server just waits for request to finish...

Comment: A "word" is `\S+` in your case, so you need to replace `#\w+` with `#\S+`. As for the "sentence", you may even try `#[^#]+#`. So, the whole would look like `#([^#]+)#|#(\S+)` (`"#([^#]+)#|#(\\S+)"`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166876/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-wiktor-stribizew).